# how to add target blank to anchor tag to open in new window using preg_match or preg_replace

Tags: php, html-parsing, preg-replace, preg-match

How to add target blank to anchor tag to open in new window using `preg_match` or `preg_replace`?

```
$contentss = file_get_contents("http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?LinkName=pubmed_pubmed&from_uid=18032633" ); 

preg_match('/<div class="rprt">(.*)<\/div>/',$contentss,$matches);  

$patterns = '/\/pubmed/';   

$replacements = 'http://ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed';   

$getreplacements = ( preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $matches)); 

echo $getreplacements[0];
```

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/php for examples of how to properly parse HTML with PHP modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for preg match/replace use [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/str_replace)

```
str_replace('<a', '<a target="_blank" ', $str);
```

You can check with preg_match if a has already got target attribute

```
if(preg_match('/<a.*?target=[^>]*?>/', $str))
```

and decide what to do then, if you want to replace this tag then use preg_replace or str_replace. You can also  decide that if it does have this tag then do no replacement. It's up to you.

`$str` is string to be replaced/checked.

To replace target when exists with **blank** you can use

```
preg_replace('/<a.*?target="([^"]?)"[^>]*?>/', 'blank', $str)
```